# PrimeFaces 5. Edit p:dataTable with p:selectOneMenu issue

Tags: primefaces

I'm facing an a weird behaviour regarding an editable p:dataTable with editMode="cell" with one of the editable columns being a p:selectOneMenu.

This behaviour only happens in IE (9, 10, edge).
When clicking on the cell the combo appears and I can choose one of the options, but I cannot choose anymore because the cell doesn't enter into edit mode again unless I click outside the cell, on another cell or outside the table.

The event is fired but the combo doesn't open.

You can check this if you load the example:

[PrimeFaces edit table showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/edit.xhtml)

and replace the h:selectOneMenu with p:selectOneMenu.

The h:selectOneMenu works all right but I want to use the filter features of p:selectOneMenu.

I hope you can help me.
Thank you very much.

Comment: I think this is a bug on primefaces, you should post this on their forum.

Comment: If you dont have pro membership, you can check if there is an issue already here https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues

Comment: i think that I have found the bug. It has something to do with an accesibility feature.